# Iterator to iterate over Excel file

Tags: python, excel, list, pandas, iterator

I have some data stored in Excel tables(`.xlsx`), which my current Python script reads them into the memory and uses them for calculations. I will explain my script more with an example.

Say my excel file has this data under a specific column: `a = [1,2,3,4,5]`.

I am reading this whole thing into the memory using pandas (`pd.read_excel()`) and running my own iterator function to get:

```
a0 = [1,2,3,4,5]
a1 = [5,1,2,3,4]
a2 = [4,5,1,2,3]
```

and so on. Basically I am shifting every element by some integer amount. `a0, a1` and `a2` here appear as lists but they are iterator objects, I don't store them.

As you notice here, `a0` is always the same as `a`, and I don't really need to store `a` in memory because I only need it once, which is what `a0` does. So what I am trying to do is having some sort of iterator object to iterate over the excel file directly to capture `a0, a1` and `a2` as if I were importing `a` first and then iterating for `a0, a1, a2` over `a`.

The reason I am trying to do such a thing is because, the time my script takes for calculations are shorter than what it takes to import the data from Excel. So in order to increase my script in performance, I need to find a way to iterate over Excel rather than saving data into the memory. I would appreciate any help with this.

Addition, my comment: If `pandas` or some other library had `readThisCell()` kind of functionality, it would make things easy for me to make my own excel iterator. But I don't know what my options are with pandas or any other library.

Comment: try :  `pd.read_excel("your_file",skiprows=1)` @Deniz

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with the pandas `read_excel` function, but we have had  good success with [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). That library lets you define a variable pointing to a specific worksheet and then iterate over that variable, as follows (pulled directly from [their tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html)):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='large_file.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['big_data'] # ws is now an IterableWorksheet

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

Comment: I read the documentation for openpyxl.load_workbook() and it looks just like what I'm looking for. However, when I use this example, it raises `TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'read_only'`. I delete the `read_only` argument, and it starts raising `KeyError: 'Worksheet big_data does not exist.'`. I can see that you directly copied the example from their website, thus it should work but yeah I'm getting these two errors. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Deniz - Replace `big_data` with the name of your worksheet, it should work. You first load the workbook, then the worksheet, then you can iterate over the rows and cells there.

Comment: Yes this works without the `read_only` arg. I have a concern though: Documentation says there is no `read_only` arg, but a `use_iterators (bool)` arg, which is for lazy iteration. When I simply set it to `True`, I am having a strange error. I can live with that but this ambiguities with documentation makes me think twice about using this library, sadly. I will be testing this library further to see if it allows me to achieve the performance increase I'm looking for. Then I will add my openpyxl iterator script here and mark your answer as accepted if everything's good. Thank you.

Comment: Even thought openpyxl only iterates, it is still slower than pandas reading and printing. Here's my script for comparison: `https://repl.it/BHRf/2`. As you can see, `pandas` reads it into the memory and then prints, that is completed in 0.77 seconds. `openpyxl` only iterated and printed, which took 1.95 seconds. Unfortunately this does not let me get some performance boost. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Deniz - I can't really speak to performance, our use cases involve pretty small files. For some reason I can't load the repl link, but I see the numbers. Not sure how to work with that.